# Android: Behaviour of a drawable svg in layer-list is not the same in API 22 or API 28 (splashscreen)

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-drawable, layer-list

I have to make a splashscreen. 
To do this, i'm using a drawable of the SVG type. I can't use a bitmap as I saw on other topics because the designer export the drawable with Adobe XD.
But the SVG is not read in the same way depending of the API level :
This one part of screen shot is on the API level 28 on a device Nokia. All is perfect <3 : 
[image]
This one is one is the ugly rendering on API level 22 on an emulator and on a LG-G6 API 23: [image]
I can't figure why and I have no idea how I can resolve this issue, it is why i'm asking help for the community.

Below the way of the implementation:

So as recommanded, I'm using a layer_list named `splash_screen.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:gravity="center"
    />
</layer-list>
```

This one is called by a style named `SplashTheme`:

```xml
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
```

Finally, this theme is applied as a theme for the `SplashScreenActivty` in the manifest :

```xml
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

```
class SplashScreenActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you import your svg ? Did you use File -> New -> Vector Asset ?

Comment: Yes, as usually.

Comment: Try using an ImageView in the layout of your splashscreen to display the logo, maybe it's an issue with the style androidWindowBackground

Comment: @Adonis320 , The ImageView can be used in an xml which will be inflate in an activity, because Imageview is a class. So I can't use it in a layer-list which, as for it,  is used as a theme before than the activity is inflated